# jquery lightbox iframe

Tags: jquery, fancybox, lightbox

I've been using Fancybox for years, but it seems things have changed with some sites blocking their content from being loaded in an iframe.  For instance, google circles, linkedin, github .. are a few that wont load in fancybox (or in an iframe).

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a workaround, or a way to use a lightbox for an external url without using an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header Sites use it to prevent hijacking.

Because of javascript's cross domain security, you can't just use JS alone. You need to use some server scripting.  [Load external site's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326297/load-external-sites-content)