# how to load another site content using php curl into a div in my site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl

I have tried by this way(according to the selected answer of "jerjer") but failed to load the content..

**[Load external site's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326297/load-external-sites-content)**

**`render.php`**

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://apps.irs.gov/app/withholdingcalculator/index.jsp';
    $htm = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $htm;
?>
```

**`common.js`**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#divId').load('render.php');
});
```

**`index.html`**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/common.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="divId"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help? Thanks in advance...

Comment: iframe. iframe. dun dun dun

Comment: no error in this code. the php script return correctly the content of the external website ? (no errors ? good path ?) Try to open render.php directly into your browser.

Comment: And why do you want to use AJAX to load render.php? Why not use php in your index? (so index.php) and just include render.php there.

Comment: I have to modify the rendered contents according to my need... means i need to deduct the some of the contents..

Comment: Make sure your server allows cURL in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. Make sure you have curl extension installed.

```
 $url = 'http://apps.irs.gov/app/withholdingcalculator/index.jsp';
 $htm = getCurlData($url);
 echo $htm;

function getCurlData($url)
{
     $ch = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
     $contents = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     return $contents;
}
```